# ubuntu 14 LTS : indigo: fail to compile default_robot_hw_sim.cpp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could not find gazebo_ros_control so lib...cloned gazebo_ros_pkgs into my catkskin. Get the following compile error: My question is , is this package ready for indigo ...I though it would pull from indigo-devel? I am running gazebo2.

default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o
Built target gazebo_ros_control
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool gazebo_ros_control::DefaultRobotHWSim::initSim(const string&, ros::NodeHandle, gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, const urdf::Model*, std::vector<transmission_interface::TransmissionInfo>)’:
/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:155:78: error: ‘struct transmission_interface::ActuatorInfo’ has no member named ‘hardware_interface_’
const std::string& hardware_interface = transmissions[j].actuators_[0].hardware_interface_;
^

/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:220:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘control_toolbox::Pid::init(const ros::NodeHandle&, bool)’
if (pid_controllers_[j].init(nh,true))
^

/home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:220:45: note: candidate is:
In file included from /home/richard/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp:45:0:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/control_toolbox/pid.h:201:8: note: bool control_toolbox::Pid::init(const ros::NodeHandle&)
bool init(const ros::NodeHandle &n);
^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/control_toolbox/pid.h:201:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
make[2]: ***

[gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros_control/CMakeFiles/default_robot_hw_sim.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172803/ubuntu-14-lts-:-indigo:-fail-to-compile-default_robot_hw_sim.cpp/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2014-06-05**:
Is this question more suited for the gazebo question board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to ros board issue should be fixed and released shortly.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0